# How to set the selected option permanent in handlebar on even refreshing the page again and again?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, mongoose, handlebars.js

I want to use the drop-down menu option in handlebar. Unfortunately I am unable to implement it via jQuery in handlebar i dont know why. So I am using the select - options menu. Below is the code:

```
<select name="sources" id="sources" class="custom-select sources" placeholder="Requirement Completed">
      <option value="profile" selected="selected">In Progress</option>
      <option value="word">Done</option>
      <option value="hashtag">Rejected</option>
    </select>
```

So what I want is that while user selects any option it should be selected permanently means it should not get reset to the default option again even after refreshing the page or after logging again.
Since this was meant to be done with dropdown bar menu but that is not workinghere in handlebar. so I am trying this with the select option menu.

How can I achieve that?

JS Code:

```
<script>

$(".custom-select").each(function() {
var classes = $(this).attr("class"),
    id      = $(this).attr("id"),
    name    = $(this).attr("name");
var template =  '<div class="' + classes + '">';
    template += '<span class="custom-select-trigger">' + $(this).attr("placeholder") + '</span>';
    template += '<div class="custom-options">';
    $(this).find("option").each(function() {
      template += '<span class="custom-option ' + $(this).attr("class") + '" data-value="' + $(this).attr("value") + '">' + $(this).html() + '</span>';
    });
template += '</div></div>';

$(this).wrap('<div class="custom-select-wrapper"></div>');
$(this).hide();
$(this).after(template);
});

$(".custom-option:first-of-type").hover(function() {
$(this).parents(".custom-options").addClass("option-hover");
}, function() {
$(this).parents(".custom-options").removeClass("option-hover");
});

$(".custom-select-trigger").on("click", function() {
$('html').one('click',function() {
  $(".custom-select").removeClass("opened");
});
$(this).parents(".custom-select").toggleClass("opened");
event.stopPropagation();
});

$(".custom-option").on("click", function() {
$(this).parents(".custom-select-wrapper").find("select").val($(this).data("value"));
$(this).parents(".custom-options").find(".custom-option").removeClass("selection");
$(this).addClass("selection");
$(this).parents(".custom-select").removeClass("opened");
$(this).parents(".custom-select").find(".custom-select-trigger").text($(this).text());
});

$("#sources").val('2');

</script>
```

EDIT:

```
  <table class="table table-hover">
    <tbody id="append_status">
      <tr>
        <th>Topic (View)</th>
        <th>Status</th>
        <th>Deadline</th>
        <th>Upload</th>
        <th>Completion Date</th>
      </tr>
      {{#each user.Addtasks}}
  <tr>
    <td><a href="profileWriter/view/{{this._id}}">{{this.topic}}</a></td>

    <td>
      <div class="center">
    <select name="sources" id="sources" class="custom-select sources" placeholder="Requirement Completed">
      <option value="0" selected="selected">In Progress</option>
      <option value="1">Done</option>
      <option value="2">Rejected</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  </td>

    <td><span id="deadline"> {{this.deadline}}</span></td>
    <td>

    </td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  {{/each}}

  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Well, your server has to tell to handlebars which option should be selected. So your server should store the selected option value in its DB so it can let handlebars know which one to select. The client's only concern should be to tell the server which option has been selected by sending the value whenever the selected option has been changed by the user. When the server receives this value it should store it again in the DB so that when the page is reloaded the selected option has been updated and can be rendered for the client.

Comment: Either your server has to tell or you need to persist the states in local storage or cache.

Comment: @EmielZuurbier  I added the JS/jQuery code. There how to get the selected value and then tell the server to persist the select option code?

Comment: @MackMon How to fetch the value now?

Comment: @Biku7 https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it is quite a lot of work to figure it all out what your application should do, I'll make an effort anyway to show you what you should do to get yourself going and in the correct direction.

First let's start with your Node server. Here you'll want to define both an endpoint from which the client can send its data to so that your server can update the value that you need to store. I won't get in too much details with the DB as I don't know the extend of your app.

Create an endpoint which you can call from the client. Something that describes what it does and where you can send the appropriate data to. In this case you have a `<select>` element called `sources` which you want to update, so I'd suggest `/update-source` would be a nice URL to send your data to. Make sure that it listens to the `POST` protocol and is able to read data that has been sent to it.

You'll need another endpoint with the `GET` protocol to navigate to so you can render Handlebars template. I assume that you already have something in place, but I've added an endpoint here below to illustrate what it should do. It should call the database and ask for the latest selected source value. That value should be passed to your template when you render it.

**Node Server**

```
// Route that receives data.
app.post('/update-sources', (req, res) => {
  // Store selected source in DB.
  res.send('Data received')
});

// Route to navigate to, if you don't have that already.
app.get('/sources', (req, res) => {
  // Retrieve selected source from DB and send it to the template.
  res.render('sources', { selectedValue: value });
});
```

---

Your Handlebars template will need some logic to determine which of the `<option>` elements should get a `selected` attribute. This logic is based on if the `value` of the option is equal to the value that has been stored. For this you'll need to write a helper function which can help you evaluate this logic.

**Handlebars helper**

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('isselected', function (selectedValue, value) {
  return selectedValue === value;
});
```

Then put it together in your Handlebars template and use the `selectedValue` you've passed from your server in the `res.render()` function to determine which option to select.

Now your client will be rendered with the correct option selected.

**Handlebars template**

```
<select name="sources" id="sources" class="custom-select sources" placeholder="Requirement Completed">
  <option value="profile" {{#if (isselected selectedValue "profile") }} selected {{/if}}>In Progress</option>
  <option value="word" {{#if (isselected selectedValue "word") }} selected {{/if}}>Done</option>
  <option value="hashtag" {{#if (isselected selectedValue "hashtag") }} selected {{/if}}>Rejected</option>
</select>
```

---

Alright, the final step: The Client. From here you can use jQuery to send your data, when it has changed, to the server. Here we'll use the `/update-sources` endpoint to send or changed data to.

With jQuery select your `<select id="sources">` element and listen for the `change` event. This event will be triggered whenever a new option has been selected. When that happens you'll want to get the new value and send it to server. From there your server should receive the new value and save it in the database.

**JavaScript**

```
$('#sources').on('change', function(event) {
  var $this = $(this);
  var value = $this.val();
  $ajax({
    url: '/update-sources',
    method: 'POST',
    dataType: 'text',
    data: {
      selectedValue: value
    }
  }).done(function(response) {
    console.log(response)
  });
});
```

Now this all is a fairly rough picture of how it all should work. You should figure out for yourself how to read the receives data from the POST endpoint and how to save and read from the database.

Alternatively you could try @MackMon' idea and look into the JavaScript Storage API.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for this! I got the flow. But this will work for one select menu and with its options. Now the thing is that I have several same select menus for each <tr> of the table on same page. I want to do the same now for all select menus. And for that I can't make that many routes for each select menu obviously. So like you have here used the registerhelper code to determine which option menu to select I need the code for selecting the select menu as well first and then afteer selecting its respective options. I have added the code in description after EDIT you can check.

Comment: Well, yes that is what you asked. Make sure that your questions are as precise as possible. If you need a follow-up on your question then I'd suggest that you open a new question and mark this answer as accepted for future readers.